# Elasticsearch sort alphabetically then numerically

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I looking for some elegant way to sort my results first by alphabet and then by numbers.

My current solution is inserting an "~" before numbers using the next sort script, "~" is lexicographically after "z":

```
"sort": {
  "_script":{
      "script" : "s = doc['name.raw'].value; n = org.elasticsearch.common.primitives.Ints.tryParse(s.split(' ')[0][0]); if (n != null) { '~' + s } else { s }",
      "type" : "string"
  }
 }
```

but I wonder if there is a more elegant and perhaps more performant solution.

Input:

```
ZBA ABC ...
ABC SDK ...
123 RIU ...
12B BTE ...
11J TRE ...
BCA 642 ...
```

Desired output:

```
ABC SDK ...
BCA 642 ...
ZBA ABC ...
11J TRE ...
12B BTE ...
123 RIU ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing at indexing time using a custom analyzer which leverages a [`pattern_replace` character filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html). It's more performant to do it at indexing than running a script sort at search time for each query.

It works in the same vein as your solution, i.e. if we detect a number, we prepend the value with a tilde `~`, otherwise we don't do anything, yet we do it at indexing time and index the resulting value in the `name.sort` field.

```
PUT /tests
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "pre_num": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\d)",
          "replacement": "~$1"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "number_tagger": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [],
          "char_filter": [
            "pre_num"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "sort": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "number_tagger",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index your data

```
POST /tests/test/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"name": "ZBA ABC"}
{"index": {}}
{"name": "ABC SDK"}
{"index": {}}
{"name": "123 RIU"}
{"index": {}}
{"name": "12B BTE"}
{"index": {}}
{"name": "11J TRE"}
{"index": {}}
{"name": "BCA 642"}
```

Then your query can simply look like this:

```
POST /tests/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "name.sort": "asc"
  }
}
```

And the response you'll get is:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "ABC SDK"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "BCA 642"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "ZBA ABC"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "11J TRE"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "12B BTE"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "123 RIU"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I like to do the change at indexing time but there is no smarter solution than add a tilde before the number? that fails to convince me.

Comment: The tilde is only added to a field you only use for sorting. Lexicographical sorting is what it is. The original input is not changed at all. The solution is the same as yours just carried out at indexing time instead of leveraging costly scripting at search time

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I would like to find another way different than save another field with the tilde (~) before the number

Comment: May I ask what bothers you about this solution?

Comment: Because I think this is rather a patch, I'm sure there must be a better way to get the same result.
Despite that your solution seems much better than mine.

Comment: I can provide another solution which figures out a sort number, but that still needs to add another field just for sorting, since you want to change the way how lexicographic sorting works.

Comment: I have no problem to add another field, but I find strange to add a tilde before a number.

Comment: The tilde is only because that's the [last ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/) so you're sure that it will be sorted last. You could add an underscore and it would yield the same result.

Comment: Since you were ready to use script sorting by adding a tilde, I thought that was a good enough solution for you. You should have stated more clearly that you knew it was a big hack and you wanted to somehow change the way lexicographical sorting was working.

Comment: I just used the tilde because I knew that would have no trouble ordering lexicographically, I also know that it is a hack but I needed a solution ASAP, so I want to find an alternative than inserting a character before the value.

Comment: Fair enough, though, you're aware that the name field is unaltered, right? i.e. you won't see a tilde anywhere in the names you get from ES.

Comment: Yes! I know that the field is not altered, but I can not find smart indexing a field with a value inserted at the beginning to solve this problem, I think there must be a more elegant solution.

Comment: So you're ok with the idea of adding another field just for sorting purposes?

Comment: Yes, now I have a field because the "name" field is tokenized. I just do not agree to add a character before the numbers.